# Codeigniter CLI working in terminal, not in Cpanel cron

Tags: codeigniter, cron, cpanel, command-line-interface

I have problems setting up a cron using CodeIgniter. I've followed the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html) and set up a test cron

```
* * * * * php /home/USERN/public_html/spider/index.php tools message
```

But this doesn't work. The output is just the index.php default controller, and not tools/message. When I run it in the terminal on the server, I get the results that I expect. Is there something I am doing wrong, or do I need to change something on the server?

Comment: You'll have to use /usr/local/bin/php

Comment: If the answer is right, (as it looks like) @ahmad add it as an answer and iSenne accept it. That way it won't remain unanswered, ;D

Comment: OK, I have added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cPanel servers, in order to for CI to use the URI segments right, You'll have to use

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```